Error collecting results from running Qiskit experiment
I am trying to run a qiskit experiment using the following code and the StatevectorSampler()
# create an instance of the Qiskit StatevectorSampler
sampler = StatevectorSampler()
result = sampler.run([qc]).result()

 
# Get results for the first (and only) PUB
pub_result = result[0]
print(f"Counts for the meas output register: {pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()}")

The error I run into stems from accessing the DataBin data type in Python:
{
    "name": "AttributeError",
    "message": "'DataBin' object has no attribute 'meas'",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 8
      6 # Get results for the first (and only) PUB
      7 pub_result = result[0]
----> 8 print(f\"Counts for the meas output register: {pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()}\")

AttributeError: 'DataBin' object has no attribute 'meas'"
}
}

This code was taken directly from Qiskit's documentation in the "Getting Started with Primitives" section.
Additionally, I found the following stack exchange post: How to run the qiskit sampler after storing measurement results on classical qubits?
and tried it out as well. I named my classical register 'cr' in my circuit for reference and still ended up not working.
Would anyone please be able to help me with this?

Can you post your full code so that we can reproduce the error?

As mentioned in the post you linked, qiskit now creates the PubResult.data object by assigning fields which name depend on your registers name, to quote the post's answer:

This is one of the biggest issues with the latest version of Qiskit
(v1.x).
To retrieve your results, the data inside the PubResult object (which
you are currently extracting by doing result[0].data) contains an
attribute which is named after the classical register. When you use
the measure_all() method, the default name qiskit uses for the
classical register is meas, so that's why your code works in that
case.

Depending on how you created your measurements, the field pub_result.data.<MEAS_NAME> will be different.
Here is an idea on how to retrieve the results from pub_result following your code:
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.primitives import StatevectorSampler

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure_all()

# create an instance of the Qiskit StatevectorSampler
sampler = StatevectorSampler()
result = sampler.run([qc]).result()

# Get results for the first (and only) PUB
pub_result = result[0]
print(f"Counts for the meas output register: {pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()}")

Note that you can always print out the variable pub_result to check which fields are present.
P.S.: Having a minimal example of code that reproduces the error would be helpful to pinpoint the error, i.e. your definition of qc is what matters here.
